# Code works perfectly on codepen but not in webstorm

Tags: javascript, html, css

The code that am trying in codepen worked, the same one does not work in webstorm.
Nothing seem to work no error showing when clicking on button,

Example

```js
const email = document.querySelector('.user-input');
const submit = document.querySelector('.btn0');
const error = document.querySelector('.mail-error');

const showError = () => {
error.style.display = 'block';
};

if (submit) {
  submit.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!email.value.match(/^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/)) {
       return showError();
    }
    document.getElementById("main0").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("main1").style.display = "block";
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="main0">
  <input class="user-input" id="input-id" placeholder="Email" onblur="">
  <p class="mail-error" style="display: none;">Please enter valid email</p>
  <div class="btn0" id="btn0id" onclick="">NEXT</div>
</div>
<div id="main1" style="display:none;">
  <p> You now have access. <p>
</div>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: It's in a js file, and i'm not getting error.

Comment: Please post the complete code and not just fragments.

Comment: @E.Maggini A [mcve] is preferred over the whole code.

Comment: @E.Maggini I've tired the same code that is up, still did not work, that means it's not the whole code.

Comment: @Sean if we are asking OP about structure of code and they have to explain in comments and there's no guide to how to reproduce in web storm.....

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding "defer" when linking to the external script file, now everything works fine.

```
<script src="script.js" defer></script>
```

Comment: Where in the html file are you adding the `script` tag? If it's above all the elements inside the `body`, that might be the problem and `defer` solves it by just loading it later.

Comment: It's in the 'head'.

Comment: Then the reason is that the HTML file is read from the top to bottom. In `<head>`, the elements you put in `<body>` tags aren't there yet. `defer` solves it by loading it later.